# Calendar facebook events

Tags: calendar, password, accounts, facebook

I am on Mavericks and have my facebook account set up correctly as i get notifications for new comments and messages but for some reason the calendar app wont get my facebook events.

I am presented with "Enter the password for “my@email.com” in System Preferences.

My password is right as the other notifications work and everything seems to work on my iphone.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How did you set up your Facebook account?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you did this but

- Go to System preferences
- Open Internet Accounts
- Pick Facebook
- In the new window check the Calender
- in the same window Click on Details and enter your credentials.
- New Calender will show up in your Calender app
- Facebook Events

That should be it.